Fix Line Out/Headphones sound echo to Microphone
I have headphones (with sep. mic and headphones) connected to Front Microphone and Headphones input. When I user this headphones as Output device then all sounds duplicates to microphone.
I also tested back ports (Line Out and Mic). It works fine on Windows after setting Echo Cancel in Realtek Audio Console.
pavucontrol:

Tried pactl load-module module-echo-cancel. It particularly solved other people voice echoing in Discord, but if i turn on music it duplicates to my microphone.
System:
Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)
Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450 AORUS PRO
$ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 1.0.4
Linked with libpipewire 1.0.4
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 695
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: e
Host Name: fedora
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.4)
Server Version: 15.0.0

After loading module-echo-cancel, pavucontrol shows Recording stream. When I play on music it shows sound on:

How to fix it?
